# Problem with basic comparisons and assignments in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compare

I've created a grid system of objects 10 units cubed, and added them to a list. I'm trying to get each object in the list to detect one another (topContact, leftContact, rightContact, bottomContact) by their position in the grid (through variables posX and posY). When I check the assignments at runtime, I find the objects with empty contacts, especially bottomContact.

I've tried `Mathf.Approximately` in case it was a float issue, I've checked and confirmed the gridList is complete and without duplicates. posX and posY are identified correctly on every gridLabel object at runtime.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GridLabel:MonoBehaviour {

    Director director;

    public float posX;
    public float posY;
    public string gridLabel;

    public GridLabel topContact = null;
    public GridLabel leftContact = null;
    public GridLabel rightContact = null;
    public GridLabel bottomContact = null;

    void Awake() {
        director = FindObjectOfType<Director>();
        UpdateName();
        PopulateContacts();
    }

    private void UpdateName() {
        posX = (transform.position.x + 35) / 10;
        posY = (transform.position.y - 10) / 10;
        gridLabel = posX + "," + posY;
        gameObject.name = gridLabel;
    }

    void PopulateContacts() {
        foreach(GridLabel grid in director.gridList) {
            if(Mathf.Approximately(posX,grid.posX) && Mathf.Approximately(posY,grid.posY + 1f)) {
                topContact = grid;
            } 
            else if(Mathf.Approximately(posX,grid.posX - 1f) && Mathf.Approximately(posY,grid.posY)) {
                leftContact = grid;
            } 
            else if(Mathf.Approximately(posX,grid.posX + 1f) && Mathf.Approximately(posY,grid.posY)) {
                rightContact = grid;
            } 
            else if(Mathf.Approximately(posX,grid.posX) && Mathf.Approximately(posY,grid.posY - 1f)) {
                topContact = grid;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the exception of border gridLabel objects, I expect all four contacts to be completed with the adjacent gridLabel. Again, I'm routinely finding missing contacts, especially the bottomContact.

The problem is probably a simple one, but I'm relatively new to C# and coding in general. Thank you ahead of time for any help you can provide.

Comment: Do not edit questions to fix typos in code when the problem in the question is solved by fixing that typo. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303113/1663383

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed bottomContact per @TimChang 's correction, but it didn't didn't solve the issue of missing contacts completely. I played around with delaying PopulateContacts() and it resolved the issue of the contacts not assigning properly. Apparently I didn't allow Unity enough time to run through the foreach for gridList before it began working with it? I'm not exactly sure but delaying the PopulateContacts fixed it. (Also new to stackoverflow, not sure if I should give Tim the check flag or on this post?)

Answer (score 0):

In the last `else if` block you again used

```
topContact = grid;
```

I guess it should be `bottomContact` here

```
else if(Mathf.Approximately(posX, grid.posX) && Mathf.Approximately(posY, grid.posY - 1f)) 
{
    bottomContact = grid;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's embarrassing. I've written and rewritten the code so many times, I must've missed that. Still, the contacts aren't populating at runtime as they should... many missing.

Comment: @Cole what do you mean by `many missing` .. there are only four so it can't be that `many`. Maybe we need some more detail here how exactly your setup looks like, what you expect to happen and where exactly it behaves different .. you know that all objects on the edges and in corners won't have all neighbors set right?

Comment: @derHugo I was unclear, I meant many of the gridLabels are missing one or more contacts. I expect that all gridLabels, with the exception of the ones on the borders, will have all four contacts assigned. The actual result at runtime are gridLabels missing one or all contacts, even when surrounded by four others.  Here is a visual of the situation: https://imgur.com/rlkKN7O  In this case I've selected all the gridLabels, but I have the 0,0 one pinned in the inspector.